# Prime counting function; is it true that $\pi(n - m) \geq \pi(n) -\pi(m)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\pi$ be the prime counting function, and $m, n$ positive integers, $n > m > 1$.

Is it proven that $\pi(n - m) \geq \pi(n) -\pi(m)$ ?

Comment: Even if you exclude the case $m=1$ it is easy to find pairs that don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modified version (with the additional requirement that $m<n-1$) is just the [second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture), which has not been proven. In fact, it has been proven that the second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture is inconsistent with the prime tuples conjecture.

Comment: Thank you. What a pity... Had it been proven, the twin prime conjecture would also be proven. I have to keep on grinding, then 

Answer (score 7):

Note that the edited form is equivalent to the question "Does every sequence of $m>1$ consecutive positive integers contain at most $\pi(m)$ primes?"

This is still false when $n = m+1$ is a prime, but perhaps you can patch this further by assuming $m < n-1.$

**Answer to original version:**

Obviously not.  Just try some values.

In particular, just by using $m=1$ inductively, this would show
$\pi(n) < 0$ for all $n \geq 2.$

Comment: I don't think "obviously not" is a great way to start this answer, especially since this is a reasonable thing to believe (and it seems like it might mostly be small cases that cause trouble).

Answer (score 4):

If we allow $m = 1$, then this statement is $\pi(n-1) > \pi(n)$, which is always false.

If we require $m > 1$, these are still equal infinitely often. For any prime $p$, choose $m = p-1$ and $n = p+1$. Then clearly $\pi(n) - \pi(m) = 1 = \pi(2) = \pi(n-m)$.

However, if we require $n > m > 1$ *and* relax the inequality to $\pi(n-m) \ge \pi(n)-\pi(m)$, this might hold for all $n,m$. Mathematica informs me it does for all $n \le 300$.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: So, if it seems to be true, how do we prove it?